# Multi tenancy app to deploy on azure at a later stage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am currently developing an MVC app using asp.net. My final aim is to deploy the saas on Azure.

But would it be feasible to do it at a later stage or should i incorporate it into my development?

When it comes to use Azure authentication etc i will require that due to the app being multi tenancy.

Just wanted to know peoples thoughts on this?

Cheers

Comment: How do you plan to authenticate under Azure? If MemberhipServices then a different staging answer than Access Control Services.  You can't really answer the staging question until you have a target Azure architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can provide more information. Do you want to know if you ignore Azure at the moment, how much effort you need to take if you decide to deploy the application to Azure? In general it would not take too much effort, unless you want to use Azure services, such as storage, ACS, and so on. Deploying an ASP.NET application to Azure web site is just like deploy to a remote IIS. Deploy to web role requires you to create an additional cloud service project. Deploy to virtual machine usually does not require any modifications to the project, but requires you to setup all the environment.

In addition, please note there’re still some difference between Azure and local environment. For example, we usually use Azure SQL Service instead of connecting to the local SQL server.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, but without developing on Azure right now. I have prepared for it though by making sure I use interfaces as much as possible. For instance, I don't write to a file system using File and Directory, but to interfaces IFile and IDirectory.

If you can avoid assuming anything based on your current localised, Windows Server environment then you can at least write implementations to satisfy requirements that do work in Azure. I'm planning to deploy to Azure and local Web servers and use Dependency Injection to satisfy the concrete implementation of the interfaces. I could just as easily use the same codebase entirely and have it detect the environment before injecting the implementations.